# Unexpected business?

Tags: phrases, expressions

When I have something unforeseen to do, what noun or expression can I use to name this activity? In general, not specifically for this case.

**Unexpected business** is what I have found. But this sounds like about money or smth formal.

It's not about work. Like I was at home and got a call. So now suddenly I need to fetch a parcel for me.

Should I say I have some **unexpected stuff, sudden stuff, business or what**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you might say this, especially if there nothing too pleasant to you about fetching that parcel.

- I have (to see about) some unexpected (little) ***task***.

You might also use the term "***personal errand***".

([ref;](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Play_Music_With_Me/irSwBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22personal+errand%22&pg=PA47&printsec=frontcover)) I need to run a personal errand and will be back for my two-thirty meeting.”

> [personal errands](https://www.google.com/search?q=personal+errands&safe=active&client=firefox-b-d&biw=1920&bih=1005&ei=hTloYOvzAbaN9u8PqsyOsAg&oq=personal+errands&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoHCAAQRxCwAzoGCAAQFhAeUJZWWKlfYPZxaAFwAngAgAHCAYgBoQiSAQMwLjmYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz): noun. a short and quick trip to accomplish a specific purpose, as to buy something, deliver a package, or convey a message, often for someone else. the purpose of such a trip: He finished his errands.

A more general  term that would still be specific enough seems to be missing; "*chore*" implies something you do regularly; I dont think it is proper in this context. There is, otherwise, the word "**something**", which is general enough, maybe too general and banal, but apparently the most useful; however, you have to add a verb (to do, to see about, to take care of, etc.).

- I have  ***something*** unexpected  ***to do***.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Witches/U9caBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22take+care+of+something%22&pg=PT99&printsec=frontcover)) Did that extend to the other boys on the team too? We finished cleaning up and opened a portal home. “I need to take care of something this evening, but I'll stop by later.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was under my nose. The word "Task" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Building on LPH's use of *something*, I think the phrase "**something has come up**" expresses that a task is both urgent and unexpected. Albeit, this phrase is often used in the context of an excuse made to put off or cancel existing plans.

Most often, I've heard this phrase as a contraction: "**something's come up**".